# Issue with Flex mobile project - bug?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, blazeds, flex-mobile

I have a problem with Flash, so that Flash Builder shows an error icon on my project (and I can't run my project) but there's no error I'm sure -> I's working on this project and there's not any error in it AND flash builder doesn't show any error on any file. Any helps? How can I resolve this problem?

Note: I'm using Flex SDK 4.6 and BlazeDS...

[image]

Comment: "but there's no error I'm sure" - I'm not so sure. Clean the project, re-build, tell us the error.

Comment: This question is confusing and full of contradictions.  If Flash Builder shows an error; what is the error? IF you can't run your project what makes you think it's working without any errors?

Comment: I've already Cleaned the project hundred times and there's no error shown...

Comment: Try cleaning the workspace.  Close Flash Builder and re-launch it specifying the '-clean' attribute as a command line argument.

Comment: Mm..Ok I've found the problem by cleaning out my workspace! Thanks www.Flextras.com !!!

Comment: I'll post that as a formal answer then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes when odd things like this happen, you can fix them by cleaning the project or the workspace.

You can clean the project by selecting "Clean" from the project menu in Flash Builder.

To clean the work space, you want to first shut down Flash Builder.  Then relaunch Flash Builder using the '-clean' command line argument.

Per the comments on the original question, your solution was the latter.